# ValidationException Importing from Redshift into Data Wrangler

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-sagemaker, aws-data-wrangler

I'm trying to build a model workflow in AWS SageMaker using Data Wrangler for preprocessing. I'm loading data from various tables in a Redshift instance, before mutating and joining them as required to build the model input data.

I'm a contractor working for a company who has provisioned some resource in their AWS environment for me to work, and am reading from a production database. If I do not load open the Data Wrangler flow early enough in the day (which I suspect is related to load on their system), some of the nodes which I have created will not validate, and instead show a red cross and the following error message:

`` RedshiftQueryExecutionIdValidationError: An error occurred when trying to invoke `describe_statement`: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeStatement operation: Could not retrieve the query result as it has expired after 1655759552. ``

The remaining un-errored nodes appear to hang in a loading/validating state. Here's a screenshot of part of the flow in this state:

[image: An image showing some currently loading AWS Data Wrangler nodes, with some errored nodes joining in towards the end of the flow, rendering the end product errored and thus unusable]

I'm not sure if it's related, but I occasionally see error messages pop up saying something about "too many inflight requests".

My main issue, I think, is a lack of context. I have not worked in this environment before, and am finding it difficult to diagnose the issue. It might be possible to provision more resource, and I could likely trim down some of the information before reading it in, but I'd like to be able to read the error messages and understand what's *causing* the nodes to error, so that I can decide on the appropriate course of action.

Can somebody please help explain what's going on here?

Comment: I would suggest opening up a case with Support and providing a HAR Capture, Studio Domain ID and App ARN(s).